# gst-launch-1.0 is showing blank screen for YUYV frame format for image size 864x480

Tags: c, webcam, gstreamer-1.0, logitech

I am trying to acquire image data from a logitech USB camera (C270 HD WEBCAM) connected to a NVIDIA Jetson Nano for image size 864x480 using the below GStreamer command but I am experiencing a blank screen attached below (which means it is not working though there are no issues).

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v  v4l2src device="/dev/video1" ! 'video/x-raw,width=(int)864,height=(int)480' ! videoconvert ! ximagesink
```

[Blank window created by ximagesink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mh6p.png)

When I try to capture the same image(864x480) with jpeg compression then it is working

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src device="/dev/video0" ! 'image/jpeg,width=(int)864,height=(int)480' ! jpegparse ! jpegdec ! videoconvert ! fpsdisplaysink video-sink=ximagesin
```

Checked both the pipeline in C programming too but same result.

Please let me know if there are any issues with the first pipeline. Thanks in advance.

-RK

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your camera does not support yuv. You can check it using.

```
v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext
```

On the other hand you might specify YUV format for the gstreamer to use. Something like this may work:

```
...  'video/x-raw, width=1280, height=720, format=YUY2' ! ...
```

or

```
... videoconvert ! 'video/x-raw, width=1280, height=720, format=YUY2' ! ...
```